# I want to get the values i get from script in a variable and console them separately like: var1.description

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got data from the script tag of the website and i stored it in a variable but i am not able to get the values single by signle as if i display data.description it gives me undefined

Here is the code :

```
const axios=require('axios');
const cheerio=require('cheerio')
  axios.get('https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/lahore/24858').then((res)=>{
    const $=cheerio.load(res.data)
var data

 data=$('.classified-listing').first().children('script').text().toString();
// console.log(data1.description)
console.log(data)
  })
```

It gives this output on console
[Here is i console it directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3omk.png)

But if i display with with this

```
console.log(data1.description)
```

It show me undefined i need to get a specific chunk of data

Need a specific chunk of data

Comment: what is ```data1``` ? You can get description by ```console.log(data.description);```

Comment: mistakely typed data1

Comment: You got a string. It is not an object. If it is JSON, you need to [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)...

Comment: getting undefined on data.description

Comment: You got undefined after you [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the variable data? `var myObject = JSON.parse(data); console.log(myObject);`

Comment: yes i both ways i got an undefined

Comment: So what does `console.log(myObject);` output? Using my code above?

Comment: Going to that url and running this in the console it is working fine parsing all of the JSON script tags in the page.
```(function(){
    const jsonScripts = 
[...document.querySelectorAll('script[type="application/ld+json"]')];
    const objs = jsonScripts.map(s => JSON.parse(s.textContent.trim()));
    console.log(objs.map(o => o.description).join(","));
}());```